# collapsible/expandable table behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

need help with some jquery/js/jsp functionality..

I have a collapsible table script:

```
(function($){ 
 $.fn.extend({  
     setupCollapstable: function(options) { 
         var defaults = { 
                displayStyle: "Image",
                autoCheckbox: true,
                toggleMinus: "/resource/images/collapse_close.gif",
                togglePlus: "/resource/images/collapse_open.gif"
        }; 

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        var toggleMinus = options.toggleMinus 
        var togglePlus = options.togglePlus

        return this.each(function() { 

            //Creating a reference to the object 
            var obj = $(this);

            //Break out the individual tbody elements
            var rowGroups = $('tbody', obj);

            //Loop through every tbody to setup collapsable and click events
            $.each( rowGroups, function( intIndex, objValue ){

                parentRow = $('th:first-child', objValue);
                childCount = parentRow.parent().siblings().length;

                if (childCount != 0) {
                    //console.log ("ParentRow: " + parentRow + " - ChildCount is: " + childCount);

                    parentRow.prepend('<img src="' + togglePlus + '" alt="collapse this section" />');

                    parentRow.parent().siblings().fadeOut('fast');

                    $('img', parentRow).addClass('clickable').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var toggleSrc = $(this).attr('src');

                        if ( toggleSrc == toggleMinus ) {
                            $(this).attr('src', togglePlus).parents('tr').siblings().fadeOut('fast');
                        } else{
                            $(this).attr('src', toggleMinus).parents('tr').siblings().fadeIn('fast');
                        };
                    });

                    var parentCheckbox = $(':checkbox', parentRow.siblings())

                    var childCheckboxes = $(':checkbox', parentRow.parent().siblings());

                    parentCheckbox.click(function(e){

                        var checked_status = parentCheckbox.attr('checked')?1:0;

                        childCheckboxes.each(function(){
                            this.checked = checked_status;          
                        });
                    });

                } else {
                    parentRow.addClass("indented");
                }

            });
                //console.dir (objValue);

        }); 
    } 
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

From my JSP I call it as such....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/js/jquery.collapstable.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('table.collapstable').setupCollapstable();
        });
     </script>
```

usage:

```
<table class="collapstable NoTableBorder">
```

when I click on the image icon the table properly collapses and expands, however I want it to be initially expanded if a certain checkbox is checked (on the JSP).

so I would have an onclick="showOrHide()" function for that checkbox input which would collapse or expand the table.

i've attached an image to for a visual representation, the collpase table is the "+/-" icon (next to the bold VISA header) while the checkbox which decides if it should be expanded for shown is the "active" checkbox..
[image: collapse]

any help with this would be amazing...

Comment: Could you please post a jsFiddle or something similar?

Comment: so what you are asking is how to write the showorhide function?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition just before the collapse / expand function call

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (checkboxname.checked){
            // Set flags to show the table expanded
        }else{
            // Set flags to show the table collapsed
        }
        $('table.collapstable').setupCollapstable();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Ravi, thanks for this!
how would I set the flags though?

i'm not familiar with jQuery so don't know how to use the flags in the setupCollapstable function

Comment: this is what my function call looks like:
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function showOrHideCard(checkboxname){
                if (checkboxname.checked){
                }else{
                }
                $('table.collapstable').setupCollapstable();
            });
        </script>

Comment: $("#[Table Id]").css("display", "block");//To expand that table
$("#[Table Id]").css("display", "none"); //To collapse that table

This table should be in a div so that you can expand that again manually.

Comment: nope, are you able to help fix the functionality? either way your post is good, was just hoping to fix the issues so it works the way I want it.